# Google Cloud SDK

Tags: eclipse

I tried to install Google Cloud SDK from the Eclipse Market Place in windows 10 and I keep getting the same error when configuring it automatically:

[image]

Comment: Is there more information in the _Error Log_ view?

Comment: This was a bug in Cloud Tools for Eclipse that has since been fixed.  Update to the latest version and the _Google Cloud SDK_updates should work again.